# Input PHP content into a CSS Selector Using Ajax/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dynamic

I'm creating a script that has a needle which points to various degrees and needs to change dynamically. The number of degrees it needs to move is located in degrees.php (In the page is just a number)
I am trying to grab the contents of degrees.php and input it into a CSS Selector to move the needle to the right direction.

What I have so far,

Below is my jquery which grabs the content from wind.php which has a number (139) for example and loads it into the DIV ID #windraw. I've then got it setting an interval for it to keep grabbing the content from that page and updating the CSS on the fly as the content changes. Then loading it into that div id tag  and.... The part which I'm stuck on, getting the content from #windraw into the CSS Selector "rotate" (https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.rotate)

jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    clearInterval(refreshId);
    $("#windraw").load("../raw/wind.php");
     });

    $(document).ready(function() {
    refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $("#windraw").load("../raw/wind.php");
    $('#winddirneedle').css('rotate', $"#windraw");
    }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

I get the error 
"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"
In my console debug however.

HTML:

```
<div id="winddircontain"><div id="winddirneedle" style=""></div></div>
```

winddircontain is a circle and winddirneedle is the needle that points to the right direction.

I'm quite a beginner in jQuery and only know a handful of it. Could someone please point out whats going wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: Just so you dont get confused, in the first part I mention degrees.php, this is meant to be wind.php

Comment: While I get the value from wind.php I can put the code from that page into this one but I did not think it was possible dynamically updating a php value into a CSS selector which is why im having to put the content in wind.php before bringing it to this page.

Comment: it is better to update your original post than to add new information as a comment.

Comment: @RST Didn't see an Edit button till just now haha my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to use $.get for this I think, rather than loading the result into a DOM element first. Also you have some syntax errors.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
    $.get('../raw/wind.php').done(function (result) {
      $('#winddirneedle').css('rotate', result);
    });
  }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I hit a wall and kept getting syntax errors but is all sorted now.